# Error while reading data from firestore in expo project

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo

I get this error:

```
ERROR  [2024-01-21T17:28:49.065Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.7.2): INTERNAL UNHANDLED ERROR:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined 
at isSafari (http://192.168.100.98:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.routerRoot=app:154341:53)
at __PRIVATE_getDefaultRelativeIndexReadCostPerDocument (http://192.168.100.98:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.routerRoot=app:181880:35)
at __PRIVATE_QueryEngine (http://192.168.100.98:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.routerRoot=app:181881:8)
at createLocalStore (http://192.168.100.98:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.routerRoot=app:187375:83)
at ?anon_0_ (http://192.168.100.98:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.routerRoot=app:187355:256)
at next (native)
at asyncGeneratorStep (http://192.168.100.98:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.routerRoot=app:7269:26)
at _next (http://192.168.100.98:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.routerRoot=app:7288:29)
at tryCallOne (/home/expo/workingdir/build/react-native-lab/react-native/packages/react-native/ReactAndroid/hermes-engine/.cxx/MinSizeRel/6q1z5s36/x86_64/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:53:16)
at anonymous (/home/expo/workingdir/build/react-native-lab/react-native/packages/react-native/ReactAndroid/hermes-engine/.cxx/MinSizeRel/6q1z5s36/x86_64/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:139:27)
at apply (native)
at anonymous (http://192.168.100.98:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.routerRoot=app:46872:26)
at _callTimer (http://192.168.100.98:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.routerRoot=app:46751:17)
at _callReactNativeMicrotasksPass (http://192.168.100.98:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.routerRoot=app:46796:17)
at callReactNativeMicrotasks (http://192.168.100.98:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.routerRoot=app:47002:44)
at __callReactNativeMicrotasks (http://192.168.100.98:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.routerRoot=app:9343:48)
at anonymous (http://192.168.100.98:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.routerRoot=app:9116:45)
at __guard (http://192.168.100.98:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.routerRoot=app:9315:15)
at flushedQueue (http://192.168.100.98:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.routerRoot=app:9115:21)
at callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (http://192.168.100.98:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&transform.engine=hermes&transform.routerRoot=app:9100:33)
```

By calling a function like this:

```
const querySnapshot = async () => {
try {
  const snapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "sales"));
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`);
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
}};
```

I have tried updating firebase and expo in my project but it always ends with the same error.

Comment: Anticipating questions - yes, my firebase config is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue here.

It seems to be a known problem of version `10.7.2` of the `firebase` package.

Here are the GitHub links relevant to the issue:

- https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/26522
- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7962

There seem to be already people working on it, but for now, a rollback to version `10.7.1` should fix the issue. It seems to be also possible to add some code to fix it, as described here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7962#issuecomment-1902290249

But I preferred to do a rollback to version `10.7.1`. If that is ok for your app, which most likely it will be, I advise you to do the same.

If you decide to rollback don't forget to remove the `^` that is usually on the version, since if you have `^10.7.1` you will end up with version `10.7.2`.

So modify your package.json to: `"firebase": "10.7.1"`

Comment: After changing the firebase version from **10.7.2** to **10.7.1**, I receive an error when starting the application: `ERROR  Error: Component auth has not been registered yet, js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes`, when I return to version **10.7.2** this error disappears

Comment: I deleted the `node_modules` directory and the `package-lock.json` file and ran `npm install`, now everything seems to work. Thanks :))

Comment: No problem, I am glad that it worked! If possible, it would be cool if you set this as an accepted answer :)